# Get where is mySaveFileDialog folder

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

hi i wanna create backup data in my application
I used saveFileDialog, so i can place backup file anywhere i want (Dekstop, drive D, etc)

```
mySaveFileDialog.FileName = "Backup Database " + dateTimeNow;
if (mySaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{
    string fileAsal = System.IO.Path.Combine(Global.myDatabaseLocation, "data.mdb");
    System.IO.File.Copy(fileAsal, mySaveFileDialog.FileName, true);
}
```

the problem is i wanna create a folder let's say 'myBackup' which contain all backup file (db, image,movie)
this is as far as I can

```
mySaveFileDialog.FileName = "Backup Database " + dateTimeNow;
if (mySaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string pathDestination = "C:\\Users\\Maju\\Desktop\\";
    string nameFolder = "myBackup";
    string fileAsal = System.IO.Path.Combine(Global.myDatabaseLocation, "data.mdb");

    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@pathDestination + nameFolder);
    System.IO.File.Copy(fileAsal, mySaveFileDialog.FileName, true);
}
```

I can't get where is user wanna placed backup file (pathDestination)
any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mySaveFileDialog.FileName contains User wanna placed backup file path.
you can use FileInfo to get it.

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(mySaveFileDialog.FileName);

\\Then you can use the properties of the FileInfo object to retrieve the
\\information you want:

fi.DirectoryName \\ the directory's full path
```

Answer (score 1):

just use   [**`FileDialog.InitialDirectory`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.FILEDIALOG.INITIALDIRECTORY%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

```
 mySaveFileDialog.FileName = "Backup Database " + dateTimeNow;
 if (mySaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string pathDestination = mySaveFileDialog.InitialDirectory;
```

Comment: it's not work
i try to messageBox pathDestination but give empty messageBox